# CNN Model always giving the same output despite using different input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I've made an AI model with a validation and test accuracy about 0.85 , which in my case I consider to be very good. My model is working with 8 different classes in which I have different car models that I want the AI model to recognize. I have about 400-500 images per class so it rounds up to about 3.5k images. The model is finished with compiling and I've saved the model and then loaded it with this code

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
new_model = load_model('models/resnet_model.h5')
```

this is how I loaded the images to train the model

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Load images and apply preprocessing
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    shuffle=True,
    image_size=(256, 256),  # Resize images to match the input size
)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)  # Scale pixel values to [0, 1]

data = data.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
```

and this is how I load the images to manually test them with the .predict function

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

image_path = "pezo2.jpg"

image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_image(image)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)
normalized_image = normalization_layer(image)

target_size = (256, 256)
resized_normalized_image = tf.image.resize(normalized_image, target_size)

imageArray=np.array(resized_normalized_image)

# Make a prediction
yhat = new_model.predict(np.expand_dims(imageArray, axis=0))
```

It always outputs this same array no matter which car model image I use, I checked if the image I load is the one I want and it is.

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

When I run the code like this ( test_data was loaded at the start of the code with tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory and then taken from the array of images)

```
# Evaluate the model on test data
test_loss, test_accuracy = new_model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels_encoded_onehot)

print("Test Loss:", test_loss)
print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)
```

This is what my model looks like

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense,Dropout
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam

resnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(256, 256, 3))

# Add custom classification layers
x = resnet_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)

# Create a new model with ResNet50 base and custom classification layers
model = Model(inputs=resnet_model.input, outputs=predictions)

optimizer = Nadam()
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels_encoded_onehot,
                    validation_data=(val_data, val_labels_encoded_onehot),
                    epochs=100)
```

it gives me an accuracy of 0.85 which is pretty good, but when I run it manually it doesn't work at all, can anyone help me with this?

I've tried everything , changing the way I load the image I want to test on , changing the model but to no avail it always gives the same array where it is 100% certain it is the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Check the image dimensions.
Make sure that the image you are loading is the same dimensions as the images that were used to train the model. You can use the `image.shape` property to get the dimensions of an image.

Comment: I resize the images to 256x256 in both cases so I don't think it's that :(

Comment: If the second class is the most common class in your dataset, try balancing the dataset by adding more images from the other classes.  And If the model is not trained on enough data from the other classes, try training the model on a larger dataset.

Comment: I've checked if it has the most images, it has 522 images in the folder but I have another class with 513 images so it's a small difference, I could be wrong but I doubt this makes the difference